# Accessing method variables on Chain Of Command D365

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

Is it possible or how to access method variable on Chain of Command? Please see code for visualization.

```
//Standard class

    abstract class SalesFormLetter extends FormLetterServiceController 
    {
        static void main(Args _args)
        {
            SalesFormLetter salesFormLetter;

            //standard business logic here
        }
    }

//Class extension

    [ExtensionOf(classStr(SalesFormLetter))] 
    final class KTI_DRD_SalesFormLetter_Extension 
    {
        static void main(Args  args)
        {
            next main(args);

            //how can I get the salesFormLetter variable used on base method?
        }
    }
```

I need to get the salesFormLetter variable for me to do additional business logic to add/update records on customized table.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to achieve this. You need to use another method to add your logic, e.g. the `run` method:

```
[ExtensionOf(classStr(SalesFormLetter))] 
final class KTI_DRD_SalesFormLetter_Extension 
{
    public void  run()
    {
        next run();

        // put your logic here
        this.myMethod();
    }
}
```